# Setting up a dynamic rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller and a view (ctrler)

controller

```
    def index
       ...
    end 

    def show
        @text = params[:text]    
    end

end
```

View (show.html.erb)

```
<%=@text %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :ctrler

match 'ctrler/:text' => 'ctrler#show'
```

If I fire the `rails s` server up and load up `http://localhost:3000/ctrler/hiiiiiii` I get nothing but if I load `http://localhost:3000/ctrler?text=hiiiiii` I get text!

Im still trying to get the hang of rails I'm used toPHP but can someone give me some guidance here am I on the right track or have I missed something out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :ctrler
```

creates the following rule

```
match "ctrler/:id" => "ctrler#show"
```

This route conflicts with

```
match 'ctrler/:text' => 'ctrler#show'
```

In the event of a conflict, the rule that appears first takes precedence, so when you go to 'ctrlr/hiiiii', it is setting the id parameter to hiiiii, not the text parameter. Try to change routes.rb to

```
match 'ctrler/:text' => 'ctrler#show'
resources :ctrler
```

and see if that helps.